# Mınt Gas Fee Problem

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-deployment, mint, presale

We have started the Mint sale of our new collection on Ethereum, but we cannot solve the gas fee problem. There is an unbelievably high gas fee. What should we do? Did we do something wrong in the Contract?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do. It depends how busy the network is and when lots of NFT drops happen at the same time it gas gets expensive. Assuming you're on Ethereum mainnet.

Whether your contract could be optimised is hard to know without being able to see any code.